# how to install zip package from cd on ubuntu server using command line?

Tags: installation, package-management, command-line, cd

i installed ubuntu server, don't have internet connection but have  .zip package on a cd.
how do i install it?

mounted the cdrom already and can see the application

Comment: Please clear it -- Do you want to install from zip package or extract it in a location?

Comment: i want to know how to install a package from cd..do i need to extract it first...cant use apt-get since i don't have internet on the machine

Comment: What is the content of the zip file? Depending the content the installation method changes.

Comment: xorg-xserver-server.zip

Comment: not the name, the contents of what you are trying to archive?

Comment: Install a desktop interface on ubuntu server

Answer (score 3):

1) Unzip the *archive.zip* to *path/to/extracted/content*:

```
unzip /path/to/archive.zip -d path/to/extracted/content
```

2) Install the archive content :

- if it's a *package.deb* :

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i path/to/extracted/content/package.deb

  sudo apt-get install -f
  ```
- if it's an *install-script* :

  ```
  sudo bash path/to/extracted/content/install-script
  ```

3) Delete the installation files (*package.deb* or *install-script*) :

```
rm path/to/extracted/content/package.deb
```

or

```
rm path/to/extracted/content/install-script
```

---

For further needs :

- To go into *path/to/somewhere* :

  ```
  cd path/to/somewhere
  ```
- To see what's inside *path/to/somewhere* :

  ```
  ls -a path/to/somewhere
  ```
- To read a *text-file* (any format, like .txt, .html, .sh, ...) :

  ```
  cat  path/to/text-file
  ```
- To edit a *text-file* (any format, like .txt, .html, .sh, ...) :

  ```
  nano path/to/text-file
  ```

Comment: thanks i didnt ubuntu server comes without unzip package..gotta install this one now